# Formulas and values in AppleScript and Numbers

Tags: numbers, applescript, formula

I'm trying to use the value of a cell in Numbers in another place in Numbers.

Using the formula works, but when I use AppleScript to use that value in another formula on a different sheet, I found out it's passing the formula, not the value.

```
set value of (cell "D2") to "=AVERAGE(E3:E1460)"
set value of n to (cell "D2")
```

I'm getting `"=AVERAGE(E3:E1460)"` instead of `14.56` for `n`.

How do I get the value `14.56`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the **value** (number, date, text, boolean, or missing value) : The actual value in the cell, or missing value if the cell is empty.

Change:

```
set value of n to (cell "D2")
```

To:

```
set n to value of (cell "D2")
```

---

If you want the *formula* of a `cell`, use, e.g.:

```
set f to formula of (cell "D2")
```